# Function to calculate max value of int not returning desired result

Tags: c

I'm just starting out learning C. I'm trying to find the max value of an int by calculation (actually I'm trying to find the max value of a float through the same method, but I want to test it on int first).
The logic seems to be OK, but my function always returns 0 at the end.

```
int max_int_helper(int base) 
{
  int prev_i, next_i, counter;
  counter = 1;
  prev_i = next_i = base + counter;

  // found max
  if (next_i < base) {
    printf("WE RETURN BASE %d\n", base);
    return base;
  } else {   
      while(prev_i <= next_i) 
      {
        prev_i = next_i;
        counter *= 2;
        next_i = base + counter;
      }
        max_int_helper(prev_i);
  }
}
```

I call it in my main function like this

```
printf("max int calculated: %d", max_int_helper(0));
```

But when I run the thing I get this:

WE RETURN BASE 2147483647
max int calculated: 0

I explicitly put the printf statement, so that I'm "sure" I only return once and the value is correct.

Please point me out where it's going wrong.

Comment: You *do* know that integer overflow is undefined, right?

Comment: Well, have a look at the C standard. C11 draft standard n1570 (openly available on the web): `6.5 Expressions, Section 5 If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined.`

Comment: allright, thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a recursion. You need to return the value of it.

So in the last line it should be:

```
return max_int_helper(prev_i);
```